# How to prevent function from generating same sets of random number in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I developed some code to generate five arrays of six numbers between 1 and 49. I used `arc4random_uniform(49)` function to try to do just that. However, when `appendArrays()` is producing same set of number for all five loops.

```
 class six49: lottery {

    var price: Int
    var winner: [Int] = []

    override init(draws: Int, lines: Int){

        price = 3
        super.init(draws: draws, lines: lines)
        }

    func appendArrays(win: inout [Int], win2: inout [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {

        while win2.count < lines {

            while win.count < 6 {

                let selection = arc4random_uniform(49)

                if win.contains(Int(selection)){
                    continue
                } else {
                    win.append(Int(selection))
                    win = win.sorted()

                }
            }

            win2.append(win)

        }

        return win2

    }

}


let result = six49(draws: 1, lines: 5)

var arr2: [[Int]] = []
var arr1: [Int] = []
var collection = result.appendArrays(win: &arr1,win2: &arr2)

print(collection)
```

Here is output:

> [[11, 16, 27, 31, 37, 39], [11, 16, 27, 31, 37, 39], [11, 16, 27, 31, 37, 39], [11, 16, 27, 31, 37, 39], [11, 16, 27, 31, 37, 39]]

I have been looking everywhere to try to create different set of number every loop, but I can't seem to find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you never reinitialize the `win` array.  Once it has `6` numbers, it never changes so you just keep appending the same `win` array to your `win2` array of arrays.

Instead of passing `win` as an `inout [Int]` into your `appendArrays` method, create a new `win` array each time in your main loop.

```
func appendArrays(win2: inout [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {

    while win2.count < lines {

        var win = [Int]()

        while win.count < 6 {

            let selection = arc4random_uniform(49)

            if win.contains(Int(selection)){
                continue
            } else {
                win.append(Int(selection))
                win = win.sorted()                    
            }
        }

        win2.append(win)            
    }

    return win2        
}
```

---

Also, it isn't clear why you're passing `win2` in since `appendArrays` returns the final value anyway.  You could just create `win2` inside of the function.

Also, you can sort the array once before adding it to `win2`.

If you want numbers in `1...49` then you need to add `1` to your `arc4random_uniform(49)` number.

```
func appendArrays() -> [[Int]] {
    var win2 = [[Int]]()

    while win2.count < lines {
        var win = [Int]()

        while win.count < 6 {
            let selection = Int(arc4random_uniform(49) + 1)

            if !win.contains(selection) {
                win.append(selection)
            }
        }

        win.sort()

        win2.append(win)
    }

    return win2
}
```

Comment: Learned a lot from this. Thank you!

Comment: Better to use a `Set<Int>` for this.